# Facebook Php SDK instantiate

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

my problem is:
I downloaded Facebook Php SDK from: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk
I put all in a folder an created my index in this way:

myAppFolder:

- src
- index.php

In my index.php I tried this code:

```
require_once("src/facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => 666, 'secret' => 616));
die("why not zoidberg?");
```

But my app doesn't die and doesn't return anything, some ideas?

Next I tried this code, but only the first echo is displayed:

```
<?php     
echo "This is visible";
try{
require_once "src/facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                'appId' => '666',
                                'secret' => '616',
                                ));
}catch(ErrorException $e){
        echo error_reporting(E_ALL);
        die(var_dump($e));
}
die("This is not visible");
```

My output is:

```
This is visible
```

Comment: Make sure you have full error reporting on, that way you will see the notices, warnings, errors, etc. I expect you will see a little more then.

Comment: I have no error, i tried also try catch expression, but the code doesn't return anything!

Comment: Do you have your error_reporting and display_errors set to sensible values?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't know how to do this.(Sorry for the bad English)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
Also make sure you have display-errors on.
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: Did you try user login functionality?

Comment: @ErwinMoller I added error_reporting(E_ALL); at the start of the code, but nothing new happens...

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan It doesn't happen anything, the user login neither, the code seems stuck when I initialise Facebook object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I didn't have Json and Curl installed ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly for me:

**index.php**

```
<?

  require_once('src/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'myappId',
    'secret' => 'mysepratecode',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have created a php-sdk folder?

Comment: That's another way of doing it, but in your case this code should also work. Just ignore the comments,  i am removing that.

Comment: wait wait, I open my website outside facebook, it is on an apache server, it's a virtualhost, and I got: Server Error 500...

Comment: It seems that the require_once('src/facebook.php') desn't work to me.

Comment: try to change the folder structure.